# Запретить камере проходить сквозь объекты

Tags: unity3d

На сцене имеется камера, на которой я могу свободно летать. Как можно сделать чтобы эта камера не залетала под террейн или другие объекты которые находятся на нем.?

Comment: Sphere Collider

Comment: @Yaroslav Поподробней если, можешь объяснить?

Comment: Привязать на какой-либо объект, добавить твердости и коллайдер.